# ON clause variables order - optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

In the 2 queries below the result set would be the same, but I was wondering if there would be any difference in speed because of the order of the comparison arguments in the ON clauses.

In the first query it matches `table1.c1 = table2.c1`, and the second the other way around.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.c1 = table2.c1)
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table2.c1 = table1.c1)
```

Comment: If there was a difference, it would be a serious reason to consider dropping the product - SQL is meant to be expressing "what you want", not "how to do it". You've expressed the same desired output in both cases, it should produce the same query plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries are strictly the same, there is no difference between them.

It just a convention to use the first form:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.c1 = table2.c1)
```

Comment: Thanks, as I expected but has been bugging me for the last few days.

Comment: In this matter, the most important than this, is that you have to understand well: [**The Logical Query Processing phases**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/) .

Answer (score 0):

Ever since the boolean expression inside ON clause returns TRUE, a record will be send to the result set output. If one of the tables returns 0 record, even if the ON clause returns TRUE, result set will be empty. So there is no difference that how you'd like to write a boolean expression inside the ON clause. Like this which means Cross Join!

Cheers

```
Select  *
    From    dbo.Person  As  A
    Inner   Join
        dbo.PersonOrder As  B
    On  1       =   1
```